# How large interval chosen to contain the mean

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

I have tried to solve the following, but not getting the right answer.

Suppose the population variable X is N(3, 0.3) and n = 20. How large an interval must be chosen so that the probability is 0.95 that the sample mean  ¯  lies within ±a units of the population mean μ?

My approach was:
As sample size is less than 30, used t statistic at 0.95 CI with 20-1= 19 degree of freedom.
t statistic at 0.95 CI with 19 degree of freedom is 2.093
Standard error = (0.3*0.3)/sqft(20). = 0.02012

3 +- (2.093 * standard error)

= 3+- (2.093 *0.02012)

Comment: Because you know the population parameter, this is not a statistical test: it's purely a probability calculation.  The Student t statistic is irrelevant; the issue with small sample sizes is irrelevant, too.  Where did your SE of 0.2012 come from??  What is the value of "$\pm a$"?

Comment: @whuber I agree with you to some extent, but I mostly think this is sloppy phrasing about calculating confidence interval width.

Comment: @Dave The question is clear and makes sense as an exercise in making computations with the Normal distribution.  Thus, we should be generous and read it as it has been stated rather than accusing it of being sloppy.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the response. I have quoted the question as it is

Comment: In that case any valid answer will be in terms of the variable $a.$

Comment: (a) Is the variance of your normal dist'n? $\sigma^2 = 0.3$ or $\sigma^2 = 0.3^2 = 0.09?$ (b) To repeat @whuber's question: "Where did your SE of 0.2012 come from?" What you have makes no sense. (c) Forget about t .// Let $\bar X_n$ denote the mean of a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma).$ Then  you must have an eqn (in vicinity of intro. to CLT) saying $\bar X_n \sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n}).$ Thus $P(\mu-1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n} < \bar X_n < \mu+1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n})=0.95.$ You seek $a = 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Plug in numerical value of $\sigma.$ Solve for $n$ in terms of $a$